# What is the function of "careful" in the "You be careful!" command

Tags: imperative-sentences

If I were to write, "You be careful!", you is the subject, but is the verb...what is careful?
I know it's an imperative, but is it an adjective?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence

> You be careful!

- ***You*** = subject
- ***be careful*** = [predicate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/predicate)

Now the predicate "be careful" is formed of

- the linking verb ***be*** in the imperative
- the predicative adjective ***careful***

About predicative adjectives, [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/predicative-adjective-1691656) says:

> *Predicative adjective* (also called predicate adjective) is a traditional term for *an adjective that usually comes **after a linking verb*** rather than before a noun. (Contrast with an attributive adjective.) Another term for a predicative adjective is a ***subject complement***.

Answer (score 0):

[**Careful**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/careful) is an adjective:

> [Merriam-Webster] 
>   adjective
>   **1 a** : marked by wary caution or prudence
>   // be very *careful* with knives

The verb is *to be*.

The construction is the same as *(You) be strong!*

---

If it were an adverb, the construction would be something like *(You) play on the street*  ***carefully!***